# pushViewController:HomeButton without reloading every time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationitem, uinavigationcontroller

I have a custom homeButton in my iphone app on every view and the way I have written code, it reloads the homeView-which has the menu page with all the other buttons. On the contrary, I observe that when I click the back button(navigationItem), it does not reload the page. I would like to implement a similar functionality for my HomeButton too so that my app is much more efficient. This is the code I have written currently. Can anyone help me just fetching the viewController instead of reloading it again. Thanks

```
 -(void)homButtonClicked{
if(homeView == nil)
    homeView = [[ViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController  pushViewController:homeView animated:YES];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly each time you click on 'home button', you would like to load `homeView` which is of `ViewController` class. Why don't you just load the `ViewController` as the initial view controller of your `UINavigationController`. And each time you click on the home button, call the function `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` which will be your `ViewController` home menu?

Comment: I was already making the home page as the rootView. Thank you. The popToRootViewControllerAnimated worked like a breeze :)